# Obtain thread handle from thread id of ANOTHER process

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, winapi

First off, I'm quite surprised that Google showed absolutely *nothing* about this specific question, despite it being necessary to implement even a bare-bones Win32 debugger using the Win32 debugging functions as documented in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The necessity of what I am asking for arises when a *debugger* process returns from `WaitForDebugEvent`, gets any event, and in the DEBUG_EVENT structure is a `DWORD dwThreadId` member, which of course is a thread ID of the *debuggee* process. Now, I want to manipulate this *debuggee* thread using `Get/SetThreadContext`, which only accepts `HANDLE hThread`. So, I need some way to get a HANDLE from a thread ID, but there does not seem to be a way to do this for another process (`OpenThread` only works for the current process).

But the reason why this is *necessary* to implement a bare-bones debugger is when the *debugger* is to handle an `INT3` breakpoint, the *debuggee* has already executed the `INT3` instruction, and the EIP needs to be decremented to account for that, hence the need for SetThreadContext. So if I can't do this, I can't even implement something as rudimentary as INT3 breakpoints!

Bottom line is, there has to be a way, some undocumented way (not even anything popping up in Google!), because of all of the existing, working debuggers out there, perhaps some undocumented function in `ntdll.dll`?

All of the information I could find on Google about the Win32 implementation of INT3 breakpoints simply use the `hThread` retrieved from the initial call to `CreateProcess`, and this works perfectly when the debuggee only has one thread, but that is a severe limitation obviously.

Comment: INT3?  Are those still used?  AFAIK, breakpoints are now handled by built-in debug registers?

Comment: On the x86 anyway, AFAIK i think hardware debug registers only allow like 4 addresses or something?

Comment: Maybe..   Debuggers are magic anyway:)  If I could just get more SO posters to use them before posting their stuft linked-list codes....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, I'm an idiot. `OpenThread` works for all processes apparently, I thought it didn't because it doesn't accept a process ID/handle. So I was looking and thinking in all the wrong places.

Comment: Thread IDs are global and unique, just like process IDs are. So there is no need to refer to a thread relative to a specific process. If you have the thread ID, you can access the specific thread. This is also why other things, like `PostThreadMessage()`, don't take a process ID/handle, either.